# Question about performance

Tags: opengl

I'm new of the topic, and today, I tried my first OpenGL program. It simply drawa a particular  figure to the screen, and allows the user to rotate around it with buttons.

Writing code, I was thinking about rendering. When I create a list with `glBeginList` and I rotate, I cancel the figure on the screen and rotate the camera, before redrawing the figure.

Do I have to cancel everything and redraw for animation, or is there another way?

Comment: I can't understand what you are asking about starting with "When I create a list...".  From then on is unclear, could you try to clear that up by chance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common query among beginners, and yes, it can seem wrong that you have to redraw everything rather than just the parts that have changed.

However, your GPU prefers it if you do this.  It can make assumptions, throw away previous frames, not have to worry about preserving old data, and take faster code paths.

So yes, you should redraw everything, and don't worry about performance if you do so.